# changing font format for each sheet

Tags: vba, for-loop, foreach, fonts

I am kind of stuck with changing a font size for each sheet. I also want to change the font into bold when a value in the "E" column is below 18.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        ' format font of currently looped worksheet object feferenced by WS
        With ws.Cells.Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 9
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone


            cr = ws.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            If Cells(cr, 5).Value < 18 Then
                Selection.Font.Bold = True
            End If

        End With

    Next ws
```

Any tips for me to fix the problem.

I am getting an ***error 438*** on this line:

```
    cr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

I also tried

```
    cr = ws.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Both codes are not working...Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error have you got?
I think the code above would change the font size just fine. BUT the code changing font for cells with value under 18 to bold doesn't work.

You want to change each cell to bold, if the rule applied, right?
Try "conditional formating" (will apply each time cell value changed and < 18)  or modify your code like this (will apply each time you run the macro):

```
...
Dim i as integer
cr = ws.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 to cr 'loop through all value in column e
       If .cells(i,5).value <18 then .cells(i,5).font.bold = true
Next i
....
```

Comment: Not working I get an error 438 in the following line:

Comment: cr = ws.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Hi Tarik, does this help? cr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row . Try to understand how to spot the last cell in a row, it would help you a lot. Because there is a different between putting this line inside or outside a "With"-"End With"-section.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the answer:

```
' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        ' format font of currently looped worksheet object feferenced by WS
        With ws
            .Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
            .Cells.Font.Size = 9
            .Cells.Font.Strikethrough = False
            .Cells.Font.Superscript = False
            .Cells.Font.Subscript = False
            .Cells.Font.OutlineFont = False
            .Cells.Font.Shadow = False
            .Cells.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .Cells.Font.TintAndShade = 0
            .Cells.Font.ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone

            cr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 1 To cr 'loop through all value in column e
                   If .Cells(i, 5).Value < 18 Then .Cells(i, 5).Font.Bold = True
            Next i

        End With

    Next ws
```